# CarrierWave config.enable_processing = false does not work in test mode with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

When I run Rspec test with the following factory, it is creating the file on the local repository in public/test/company/

**carrierwave.rb**

```
if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  end
else
...
end
```

I don't understand why it is creating the file in test mode when I clearly have disabled processing. I want to run my test suite without processing and storing images. Any hint on what to change?

**image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process resize_to_fit: [250, 250]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [75, 75]
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png svg)
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= "#{mounted_as}.png" if original_filename.present?
  end
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
factory :company do
  name  { 'stackoverflow' }
  logo  { File.new(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'companies', "1.png")) }
end
```

Comment: You are doing what the docs say you should do https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#testing-with-carrierwave. Maybe you can try doing some debugging to be sure that branch of code is being executed in the initializer, looks like there's something else going on

Comment: @arieljuod - If I kill the process with a binding.pry in the initializer I get the expected result ```CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.enable_processing = false ```. And I also get the same result if I kill the process in the uploader. 

The error I get when I run the test is ```Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /company # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/carrierwave-2.2.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:308:in `mkdir!' ```